# How can we design a SeekBar with custom Thumb UI and a Text inside it and custom SeekBar Track UI?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-seekbar

How can we design **SeekBar** with a custom **Thumb** and **Text** inside it and a custom **SeekBar** **Track** **UI** as shown below?

[image]